# Out of range error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I was trying to implement hacker news algorithm using mysql and got the following error

```
    Double value is out of range in 
    pow(((unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(postDateTime))/3600 + 1),1.5)

Where the value of postDateTime is 2012-12-15 10:41:31
```

If i implement the above as

```
pow(((unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(cast(postDateTime as signed)))/3600 + 1),1.5)
```

Its working perfectly but i am not understanding the reason behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of mysql are you running? Check [this link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61224) out.

And check [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to understand why you are getting negative values:

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
>   is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument
>   as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string,
>   a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or
>   YYYYMMDD. The server interprets date as a value in the current time
>   zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC.
>
> ...
>
> If you want to subtract UNIX_TIMESTAMP() columns, you might want to cast the result to signed integers. See Section 12.10, “Cast Functions and Operators”.

Comment: Thanks but i am not able to understand why i am getting negative result with unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(postDateTime)

Comment: @Tarun: Is `postDateTime` a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column?  What is the current time in your session timezone?  `SELECT NOW()`?

Comment: @eggyal Its DATETIME,and you ere right there seems to be something wrong with mysql and php timezone,the result of SELECT NOW() i 2012-12-15 07:14:21

Comment: Okay.  Because it's `DATETIME`, it is taken to be in the session's timezone for the call to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`; since the current time in the session's timezone is earlier than `postDateTime`, the resulting subtraction is negative.  You may need to set your session [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) appropriately: `SET time_zone = ...;`.